# How to use a single async web service call repeatedly in a stream of cancellable requests?

Tags: .net, async-await, system.reactive

In my WPF UI, I have a list of customers. I also have a Web API service for fetching a single customer's profile. Both the server side and the client side are built using `async`/`await` and are cancellable.

When the user selects "Customer A" from the ComboBox, it triggers the server call to fetch the customer profile. After 2 seconds (the contrived duration of the server action method) the data returns and is displayed. If, during that 2 seconds "Customer B" is selected, my code cancels the first request and fires off the second request.

This all works great, the is-busy/cancellation logic is fairly naive and doesn't cancel properly if the user very quickly selects different customers. For example, if I press the down arrow key (with the combobox having focus) 10 times quickly, 5 of the requests are correctly cancelled on the server side and 5 of the requests are not. While this isn't the end of the world, I don't want to chew up server resources with potentially big database queries running in parallel for no reason.

Here is my client code:

```
CancellationTokenSource _customerProfileCts;

//called when a new customer item is selected from the UI's ComboBox
private async void TriggerGetCustomerProfile()
{
    //if there is already a customer profile fetch operation in progress, we just want to cancel it and start a new one. 
    if (IsBusyFetchingCustomerProfile)
    {
        _customerProfileCts.Cancel();
    }

    try
    {
        IsBusyFetchingCustomerProfile = true;
        IsCustomerProfileReady = false;
        await GetCustomerProfile();
    }
    finally
    {
        IsBusyFetchingCustomerProfile = false;
        _customerProfileCts = null;
    }
}

private async Task GetCustomerProfile()
{
    _customerProfileCts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    await _customerSvc.GetCustomerProfileReport(SelectedCustomer.Id, _customerProfileCts.Token);
    //logic for checking result of web call and distributing received data omitted
}
```

I feel like there should be some well-established pattern for this kind of thing, that ensures that every single request is cancelled if a new UI items is selected, no matter how fast the user selects.

In fact, isn't this one of the highlighted use cases for reactive extensions? I see lots of mention of hypothetical problems like calling a search web service after keystrokes are entered in a textbox, but I have not found any example that deals with cancelling previously sent requests.

I just need something clean and rock-solid, hopefully something that can be packaged up and hide the complexities so that this kind of cancellable-async-fetching can be used elsewhere in my app trouble-free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that your `finally` is modifying `_customerProfileCts`, which can `null` out instances that are still in use by other calls. If you move that to after the `Cancel`, then it should work fine. In fact, you can combine it with the modification in `GetCustomerProfile` as such:

```
CancellationTokenSource _customerProfileCts;

private async void TriggerGetCustomerProfile()
{
  if (_customerProfileCts != null)
  {
    _customerProfileCts.Cancel();
  }
  _customerProfileCts = new CancellationTokenSource();
  var token = _customerProfileCts.Token;

  try
  {
    IsBusyFetchingCustomerProfile = true;
    IsCustomerProfileReady = false;
    await GetCustomerProfile(token);
  }
  finally
  {
    IsBusyFetchingCustomerProfile = false;
  }
}

private async Task GetCustomerProfile(CancellationToken token)
{
  await _customerSvc.GetCustomerProfileReport(SelectedCustomer.Id, token);
}
```

Comment: That worked great! There was a small side-effect where my `IsBusyFetchingCustomerProfile` busy indicator was being reset in the `finally` of the cancelled call, moments after the new call set it high. I used your `AsyncLock` to wrap the `try/finally` and it solved the issue.